# Restore BIOS password by dumping ROM?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, passwords

I've set the Supervisor Password on this Acer E3-112M notebook in order to install Fedora in UEFI Mode. Long story short, the prompt seems to accept certain symbols when setting the password but not when prompting for it, and now I'm stuck without being able to access the BIOS. I'm wondering if it's possible to dump the BIOS of one chip and then dump it into mine. I've got a friend with the exact same model of the notebook but his doesn't have the supervisor password set. Is it possible to dump the firmware ROM to a file from his laptop then dump it to mine to restore its "factory status"?

Also, I haven't found any information about how to "short-reset" this BIOS or clearing the CMOS (most Acer methods don't work in this one, the password stays) and I also haven't found much info on this model.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No;  Its not possible to dump the contents of the firmware to a file, then use the dump, and overwrite what you have.

Comment: Any insight as to why this is not possible will be very appreciated.

Comment: What you dumping isn't in a binary format.  You are dumping the contents in a textual format.  As I can't see what the post say specifically ( one of the reasons the relevant information should be in the question itself ) my comment is based on many many years of dealing with embedded electronics and computers overall.

Comment: Ok, I understand, and that's why I didn't include the complete question in my post, I'm not asking if *that method* works, but if is there a way to dump a BIOS, pretty much like how the *BIOS upgrade utilities* work.

Comment: Those utilities upload compiled source binary.  What you are dumping certainly isn't going to be that.  I can't view the link because its blocked, I will come back to this question, when I can see the method described.  Confused on the reason you remove the link instead of just including the content.

Comment: Because, as you said, relevant information should be in the question, and since it's not relevant (doesn't add or enhace the information already wrote here), I removed it. But then again, is there a way of dumping such *compiled* binaries to a file and then back to my own chip?

Comment: They're similar, but it's not a duplicate, on the first one I'm asking how to clear the password and in this one I asking whether it's possible to dump a chip in order to clear it. Man, there's no need to make such statements, are you always such a rude guy or do you only answer when you're in a bad mood? I'm not asking for anyone to do research, I'm doing mine as I write, and if you don't know something, just don't reply. No need to be rude.

Comment: I am not being rude.  Flagging your question as a possible duplicate isn't being rude.  I asked for some information, and for you to kindle include information from a link, you have address those concerns.  In researching the problem I found your other question, and feel to it being nearly identical, it could simply been improved.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same goal, just using two completely different methods, how's that a duplicate? Or even nearly identical? But whatever, thank you for your time.

Comment: Your other question is a duplicate, asking different methods to solve the same problem is not two different Questions.

Comment: Most manufacturers have a master password to allow entry into the bios (mp is specific to each pc), call Acer support to see if they will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that. Just for the record, if that's the reasoning, are you saying that, for example, asking how to set up an FTP server, then asking how to set up an SMB one would be duplicate questions? The goal on both is accessing files remotely.